# Auto increment column each time 1,2,3 SQL server

Tags: sql-server, syntax, auto-increment, identity

I have temp table each time store 100 values based on a specific condition.
I need Slno as 1,2,3,4 ...100 each time query executes .

If I use below syntax's, the 'Slno' is taking some other numbers

```
create table #temptable
(Slno  INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
 Name varchar(50) 
)

create table #temptable
(Slno int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY ,
 Name varchar(50) 
)
```

Please help if there is a way out without using Rank()?

Comment: The difference between the two is that you select a PK with the second option. Otherwise, they are the same. You will have to handle the row order upon `INSERT` though

Comment: okay i had to use Row no function

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017) column as follows:

Syntax:

```
 CREATE TABLE (
      ID_column INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
      ...
    );
```

It should be

> **Identity(seed,increment)**

Here you go:

```
 CREATE TABLE #temptable
    (Slno INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     Name varchar(50) 
    )
```

Example:

```
INSERT INTO #temptable (Name) Values ('ABC')
INSERT INTO #temptable (Name) Values ('ABhshC')
INSERT INTO #temptable (Name) Values ('ABQRAC')
INSERT INTO #temptable (Name) Values ('ABhsAERAYRHAERhC')

SELECT * FROM #temptable
```

Results:

```
Slno    Name
1   ABC
2   ABhshC
3   ABQRAC
4   ABhsAERAYRHAERhC
```